# incremental counter within dataframe only when a condition is met in r

Tags: r, data.table, counter

I would like to create an accumulative incremental counter that increases only when a condition is met.

```
DT <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
               b = c(10L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L))
```

I don't get the desired result with `rleid` because when two conditions are met in consecutive rows, the increment is not performed

```
> DT[,count := rleid(b>=5),id]
> DT
    id  b count
 1:  1 10     1
 2:  1  5     1
 3:  1  3     2
 4:  1  4     2
 5:  1  2     2
 6:  1  6     3
 7:  1  1     4
 8:  2  3     1
 9:  2  5     2
10:  2  7     2
```

The expected result is

```
> DT
    id  b count
 1:  1 10     1
 2:  1  5     2
 3:  1  3     2
 4:  1  4     2
 5:  1  2     2
 6:  1  6     3
 7:  1  1     3
 8:  2  3     1
 9:  2  5     2
10:  2  7     3
```

Comment: try `DT[, count := rleid(cumsum(b >= 5)), by = .(id)]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an option with `cumsum`.  Grouped by 'id', get the cumulative sum of logical expression (`b >= 5`).  For 'id' 2, the first element that is greater than or equal to 5 is at position 2 (in the grouped position), thus the first row will be 0. Inorder to make this 1, an option is to convert it to `factor` and then coerce to integer so that we get the integer storage values (`R` indexing starts from 1)

```
DT[, count := as.integer(factor(cumsum(b >= 5))), id]
```

-output

```
DT
    id  b count
 1:  1 10     1
 2:  1  5     2
 3:  1  3     2
 4:  1  4     2
 5:  1  2     2
 6:  1  6     3
 7:  1  1     3
 8:  2  3     1
 9:  2  5     2
10:  2  7     3
```

Comment: Believe me in one try! :D

Answer (score 3):

Another `data.table` option with `cumsum`

```
> DT[, count := (v <- cumsum(b >= 5)) - v[1] + 1, id][]
    id  b count
 1:  1 10     1
 2:  1  5     2
 3:  1  3     2
 4:  1  4     2
 5:  1  2     2
 6:  1  6     3
 7:  1  1     3
 8:  2  3     1
 9:  2  5     2
10:  2  7     3
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `accumulate` function for this purpose. Here are some notes on this solution:

- `accumulate` takes a two argument function as its `.f` argument where `.x` is the previous/ accumulated value and `.y` is the current value in the sequence of values of vector `b`
- I set the initial value of `count` as `1` thus remove the first value of `b` cause we don't need it anymore and check the next value by `.y` and if the condition is met it will be added by one otherwise it remains as is.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

DT %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(count = accumulate(b[-1], .init = 1,
                            ~ if(.y >= 5) {
                              .x + 1
                            } else {
                              .x
                            }))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
      id     b count
   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1     1    10     1
 2     1     5     2
 3     1     3     2
 4     1     4     2
 5     1     2     2
 6     1     6     3
 7     1     1     3
 8     2     3     1
 9     2     5     2
10     2     7     3
```